# Do Dual Flurry and Duel Savagery apply to single attacks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Dual Flurry says "Dual wielding attacks are [X]% faster." Dual Savagery says "Dual wielding power attacks do 50% bonus damage."

Do these apply to repeated single-strikes if I am currently dual-wielding weapons? That is, if I click left mouse button, and right mouse button, and alternate (swinging one blade at a time), will those swings be faster if I have Dual Flurry? Or do these bonuses only apply to the two-weapons-at-once attacks (both mouse buttons at a time)?

What about Dual Savagery? Does it affect single-strike power attacks, or only the two-weapons-at-once power attacks?

Comment: I have been wondering this one myself for a while. It would seem to me that it only affects when you attack or power attack with both at once instead of alternating but I am honestly not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Josh's answer seems incorrect. I just leveled up, and made a quicksave before putting a point in the 2nd level of the perk (+20% --> +35%). I started a stopwatch and alternated clicking the left+right mouse buttons for 10 seconds. Without the perk, I could pull off 12-13 attacks in 10 seconds, barely. With the perk, I could easily pull off 14-15 attacks. I repeated the experiment twice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by merely choosing both perks in dual flurry and observing the swinging speed, it does seem to improve the speed of all attacks while dual wielding. The speed increase seems to move all weapons 1 tier up in regards to their type. For example; a mace seems to swing as fast as a war axe, and a war axe seems to be as fast as a sword. The dual attack and dual power attack are now ridiculously fast when wielding a dagger in the left hand (which dictates the speed of dual attacks). Keep in mind that this is with BOTH perks in dual flurry, only unlocking one will not show such a drastic change, also, this is just a visual comparison, I have no concrete proof other than the fact that they seem to be faster. Still unsure if the same rules apply to dual savagery.

Comment: Followup: If you are a vampire and raise Restoration to 70 then choose the 'Necromage' perk, certain other perks are magnified as well, this being one of them. With the Necromage/Vampire combo a mace seems to swing slightly faster than a sword normally would, swords become much faster than normal and daggers become inhuman. Be cautious, however, as only perks that are chosen AFTER acquiring Necromage are affected. If you have the Dragonborn DLC and have defeated Miraak this becomes less of a problem because you can wipe perks trees and then re-choose them after acquiring Necromage.

Comment: Rather than putting follow-ups in comments, you should [edit] your post to add the additional information. This will ensure that search engines index that information and also reduce the chance that it will be missed by humans looking at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to tell that it increases attack speed and alternating is not necessary. The bonus is applied as a percentage modifier of the speed of all attacks when you are wielding two weapons. (I.e you can swing your right hand sword 35% faster with the perk supposING you have a weapon in your left hand, the same is true of the weapon in your left hand it swings 35% faster meaning you don't have to alternate both to be able to attack faster) the bonus also applies to the speed of the dual attacks giving the dual attacks and dual power attacks a 35% speed boost. Basically any attack you do when you are holding two weapons will be made faster by the perk.

Answer (score -1):

Both only apply to the specific "dual" attacks, that is the one you get when you press both mouse buttons at the same time (and optionally hold, for the power attack).

There [is a shout](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elemental_Fury) that will increase the speed of alternating weapon strikes (assuming said weapons are not bound or enchanted, which is a bit lame and nonsensical, but there you go).

Comment: Are you sure?  I have observed that Dual Flurry increases the speed of single handed attacks made *while* dual wielding.  Not just dual power attacks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain, but I admit I haven't done any kind of controlled research -- I saved my game, took the perk and swung a few times, reloaded and did the same and compared the feel. It did not seem noticeably faster. I was using daggers, maybe it's already fast enough that the speed difference was minor?